# Raster to vector conversion in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vectorization

I would like to convert a raster image into vector. My image is referenced to a specific zone (vect). 
I'm working with Hansen dataset and in particularly the layer 'lossyear'. Raster image is from a different polygon in a specific year (for example 2007) and I obtain it by the function ReduceResolution. The value of different pixel that constitute the image are float number. The code is:

`var loss_2007_vt = loss_2007_filtered_res.reduceToVectors({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: vect,
  crs: collection.projection(),
  scale:500,
  geometryType:'polygon',
});`

I received this error message: "FeatureCollection (Error)
Image.reduceToVectors: Need 1+1 bands for , image has 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not specifying the reducer.  I think it's looking for additional bands to reduce (i.e. get the mean for a homogeneous region and set it as a property of the output feature) and not finding any.

Comment: If I don't specify the option reducer of the function reduceToVectors I obtain this error message "FeatureCollection (Error)
Image.reduceToVectors: First band ('lossyear') of image must be integral".